# Filling out a table with data in a Visualforce page?

Tags: visualforce

I used the following source to create a table:

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_quick_start_iteration_components.htm

This is my VF page code:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" extensions="controllerClass">    
<apex:pageBlock title="Cases">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Case}" var="c">
     <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.AccountId}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.Status}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable> </apex:pageBlock> </apex:page>
```

This is my Apex code (which only initializes the controller):

```
public class controllerClass {
public Case myCase;

public controllerClass(ApexPages.StandardController stdController){  
    this.myCase = (Case)stdController.getRecord();     
}   }
```

As you can see, it is the same thing except mine is for Cases, yet there is no data on my table when I preview it... Could anybody point out the problem?

I have the feeling it is in the following line:

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Case}" var="c">
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've suspected, apex:pageBlockTable works on a list of items, not a single item. The original demo uses Account.Contacts, meaning it's showing the contacts related to a specific account. If you wanted a list of cases, you'd need a list of cases to start from. For example, if you wanted all cases, you could use a standardSetController:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" recordSetVar="caseRecordList">
<apex:pageBlock title="Cases">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!caseRecordList}" var="c">
     <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.AccountId}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.Status}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Or, for all cases on an account:

```
<apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:pageBlock title="Cases">
  <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Account.Cases}" var="c">
     <apex:column value="{!c.CaseNumber}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.AccountId}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.Status}"/>
     <apex:column value="{!c.Subject}"/>
  </apex:pageBlockTable> 
</apex:pageBlock> 
</apex:page>
```

Comment: It worked! However I will need the use of the extension as I progress, but I have errors when using both the 'extensions' and the 'recordsSetVar' attributes... Is there a workaround for this? Should I load the data through the extension as opposed to doing it in the VF page? If so could you point me out in the correct direction?

Thanks again for answering my question!

Comment: @Frankg26 If you use recordSetVar, your extension's constructor changes slightly: `public ClassName(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller)`. Or, you can populate the list using your extension, which gives you more control over the ordering of the records.

Comment: Thanks again! One final question, is there a source you wold recommend that I could use to populate the table with my extension?

Comment: @Frankg26 You'd typically populate your table with a query in the extension/controller, usually in the constructor.